# Flutter: separating background service to different class, cause method error

Tags: flutter

Hi so I'm trying to use background_service for my app by using flutter_background_service plugin, I've managed to follow the example from the documentation and I want to move these function to different classes for better code writing. The problem is when I move it to the other file and call the method it show an error of:

> Unhandled Exception: onStart method must be a top-level or static function

What causing this to happen ? can anyone explain it and how to fix it ? And how do I make my background_service app listen to my firestore data.. I want to detect if there's any task that almost pass the due_date.

Here's my code:
Main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await BackgroundService().initializeService();
}
```

Background_service.dart

```
class BackgroundService {
  static const notificationChannelId = 'my_foreground';
  static const notificationId = 888;

  Future<void> initializeService() async {
    final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      notificationChannelId, // ID
      'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE', // Title
      description:
      'This channel is used for important notifications.', // Description
      importance: Importance.low, // importance must be at low or higher level
    );

    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        const InitializationSettings(
          iOS: IOSInitializationSettings(),
        ),
      );
    }

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    await service.configure(
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
        onStart: onStart,
        autoStart: true,
        isForegroundMode: true,
      ),

      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
        autoStart: true,
        onForeground: onStart,
        onBackground: _onIosBackground,
      ),
    );
    service.startService();
  }

  onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
    DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
    
    /// Code about _onstrat method
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  Future<bool> _onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
    /// Code about Ios background
  }
}
```

Comment: Just change the `onStart` method signature to `static onStart(ServiceInstance service)`.  And call the function with `BackgroundService.onStart()`.

Answer (score 1):

> top-level means the function should be sits on the top of any
> hierarchy of Class or Function.

you have to put the fucntion outside of classes. read documentation here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members

- Workaround:

**background_service.dart**

```
// on start is a top-level function
@pragma('vm:entry-point') 
onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
    DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
    
    /// Code about _onstrat method
  }

// top-level function
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<bool> _onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
    /// Code about Ios background
 }



class BackgroundService {
  static const notificationChannelId = 'my_foreground';
  static const notificationId = 888;
......

 await service.configure(
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
        onStart: onStart,
      ),

      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
        onForeground: onStart,
        onBackground: _onIosBackground,
      ),
.......
```

Comment: Do you maybe know how it is possible to call invoke outside of OnStart method?